# Select the appropriate formula based on the Cell Selection

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a Macro where a selected cell (or range of cells) will have a formula in it based on its location. My issue is that I'm trying to choose from 3 different formula formats.

For example:
I would like when a cell (or range) is selected in range R10C2:R20C2 to use formula "=R5C*RC[1]"

When a cell (or range) is selected in range R21C2:R30C2 to use formula "=R3C+RC[1]"

when a cell (or range) is selected in range R31C2:R40C2 to use formula

```
"=IF(R2C7,R3C8*RC[1],R3C9*RC[1])"
```

I'm completely new to VBA and all I have is the following; the additional lines  convert the adjacent cell(s) from a formula to value:

```
Sub FormlaOptn()

  Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=R5C*RC[1]"
  Selection.Offset(0, 1).Copy
  Selection.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
  Application.CutCopyMode = False

 End Sub
```

Comment: `Intersect` might be helpful.

Comment: I don't think Intersect helps me here. I think I'm going to have to create a Macro for each formula and place the Assigned Macro Buttons above the Range of Cells. This way the user can select the cell or range and Click the button for that range. I don't think it's possible to create a single Macro for this.

Comment: It definitely is possible. Did you try to use `Intersect`?

Comment: If you know in advance in which cells which formulas are, just enter these formulas into the sheet. Why are you trying to do it with a macro if completely new to VBA? Do you want to get in the cell not a formula, but a ready-made value? Calculate this in a macro (without using worksheet formulas) and insert the result into the desired cell.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to determine if your selection (or any specified range) is within each of your 3 larger ranges (or not inside any).  Then, you can use a if / elseif / else  or a select case statement.

The range references you note are not usable by Excel.  Excel uses a cell range name like "A1" where the letter represents the column and the number the row.  A multi-cell range, looks like "A1:C5".  You may also find dollar ("%") symbols mixed in.  Those indicate absolute column and row references, which I will not cover in this response.  For your convenience, I provide a simple function, RangeMaker, to convert a fully numeric row and column range definition to the Excel style.  This is not typical, but I didn't want to completely pull the rug out from under you.

I am missing some details given your range references do not fall in normal Excel terminology.  So, in my
example code below, I take liberties.  You will have to adapt this to your intended ranges.
For this code, I am assuming the following spreadsheet data and layout.

- Column B - the column that may include formula.  Only rows 10 through 40 will be automatically updated.  Other rows will be ignored.
- column C - a column that is intended to hold a value that matches the result of the formula in column B
- Column D, E and F - column containing a numeric expression that may be used in the formula in Column B.
- Column G - a Boolean (True/False) expression that may be used in the formula in Column B.

I solved this with 3 functions or procedures plus an additional procedure, FormlaOptnDemo, that allows you to test or demonstrate the main procedure, FormlaOptn.

```
Option Explicit

' The following function tells you if one range is contained in another. You will see why we use this later.

Function RangeAContainsRangeB(RangeA As Range, RangeB As Range)
' Returns True if RangeB is entirely within RangeA, else returns False.
' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Application.Intersect
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Intersect(RangeB, RangeA)
    RangeAContainsRangeB = False
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        Exit Function
    ElseIf RangeB.Address = RangeA.Address Or rng.Address = RangeB.Address Then
        ' RangeB is completely within RangeA
        RangeAContainsRangeB = True
    End If
End Function


' You may not need the following function.  I included it, because you
' seem to want to define ranges strictly using row and column numbers
' instead of the normal Excel range address convention, CR, where C is
' an alpha representation of the Column and R is the row number.  An
' example is A2, which is the first column and the second row.

Function RangeMaker(intRow1 As Integer, intColumn1 As Integer _
                    , intRow2 As Integer, intColumn2 As Integer) As Range
    ' Convert two row / column number pairs to an Excel Range object.
    ' RangeMaker(2,3,9,11).Address returns Range [$C$2:$K$9]
    Set RangeMaker = Range(Cells(intRow1, intColumn1).Address _
                           & ":" & Cells(intRow2, intColumn2).Address)
End Function


Sub FormlaOptnDemo()
    Dim ans As String
    ' This is a wrapper around the main procedure.  It allows
    ' you to run the procedure on any arbitrary range.
    ' Default is all cells in the 3 ranges.
    
    'Prompt user for a range by name
    ans = InputBox(Prompt:="Enter a range name: " _
                   , title:="", Default:="B10:B40")
    
    ' Convert address string to range object
    ' and pass it to FormlaOptn
    Call FormlaOptn(Range(ans))
End Sub

Sub FormlaOptn(Optional rngTarget As Range)

    Dim cell As Range, rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range
    Dim blnSetFormula As Boolean
    Dim s As String
    
    
    ' If rngTarget has multiple columns, this procedure
    ' will have unintended results.  Raise an exception.
    If rngTarget.Columns.Count > 1 Then
        Err.Raise 1000, "FormlaOptn", "rngTarget must not contain" _
                    & " more than a single column."
    End If
    
    ' Debug.Print statements are in for the
    ' developer. Remove them before going "live."
    Debug.Print vbCrLf, vbCrLf, vbCrLf
    ' If not rngTarget provided, use Selection.
    ' Note that Selection may contain more than one cell.
    If rngTarget Is Nothing Then Set rngTarget = Selection
    Debug.Print "Target: ", rngTarget.Address
        
    ' Define the 3 ranges for which you want
    ' different formulae applied.
    Set rng1 = RangeMaker(10, 2, 20, 2)  ' $B$10:$B$20
    Debug.Print "Range 1: ", rng1.Address
    
    Set rng2 = RangeMaker(21, 2, 30, 2)  ' $B$21:$B$30
    Debug.Print "Range 2: ", rng2.Address
    
    Set rng3 = RangeMaker(31, 2, 40, 2)  ' $B$31:$B$40
    Debug.Print "Range 3: ", rng3.Address
    
    ' For each cell in rngTarget (the passed argument),
    ' check to see if it falls in the 3 ranges, and
    ' if so, apply the appropriate formula.
    
    For Each cell In rngTarget
        ' If the cell does not have a formula already,
        ' we won't bother making any updates.
        If cell.HasFormula Then
            ' Until we set a formula, we know we haven't,
            ' so blnSetFormula is False.  :)
            blnSetFormula = False
            If RangeAContainsRangeB(rng1, cell) Then
                ' The cell falls in range of cells to which we
                ' want to apply the first formula.
                cell.Formula = "=" & cell.Offset(0, 2).Address _
                               & "*" & cell.Offset(0, 3).Address
                ' Let's remember that we successfully set a
                ' for this cell.
                blnSetFormula = True
            ElseIf RangeAContainsRangeB(rng2, cell) Then
                cell.Formula = "=" & cell.Offset(0, 2).Address _
                               & "+" & cell.Offset(0, 3).Address
                blnSetFormula = True
            ElseIf RangeAContainsRangeB(rng3, cell) Then
                ' I'm certain this is not the exact formula you
                ' wish to use, but you can use it as a template.
                cell.Formula = "=IF(" & cell.Offset(0, 5).Address & ", " _
                                & cell.Offset(0, 2).Address & "*" _
                                & cell.Offset(0, 3).Address & ", " _
                                & cell.Offset(0, 3).Address & "*" _
                                & cell.Offset(0, 4).Address & ")"
                blnSetFormula = True
            End If
            
            ' If we set a formula for the current cell, let's copy
            ' its value to the cell to its right.
            If blnSetFormula Then
                Debug.Print "Right of Target: ", cell.Address
                rngTarget.Offset(0, 1).Value = cell.Value
            End If
    
        End If
    
    Next cell

End Sub
```